# Product List Views is not populating in Product List Performance report of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I have set up Enhanced Ecommerce using Google Tag Manager and dataLayer. Everything works well except impressions and clicks.

[image: impressions are not populating]

View and CTR for all lists is zero whilst they have been clicked 3 times. I have debugged data layer and it's sending impressions correctly.

[image]

Have you ever experienced this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution in [another community](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/Tracking_Goals_and_Ecommerce/message-id/10240/thread-id/10240#M10241). I changed the analytics trigger to DOM Ready and problem just solved.